# C-JNI returning 2D int array as a JobjectArray

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, multidimensional-array

So I decided to make a `dll` import to my java code.

What it does is calculating neighbor matrix. The issue is that I have no idea how to return matrix as a `jobjectArray`.

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_src_pathfinder_PathFinder_neighbourMatrixGenerator (JNIEnv * env, jobject b,...) {
    int i,j;
    BOOL tt=1;

    jclass intClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "java/lang/Integer");
    jobjectArray row;
    jobjectArray rows;

    int **matrix = (int**)calloc(size, sizeof(int*));

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));
    }

    for(i=0; i<size; i++) {
        row = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, size, intClass, 0);

        for(j=0; j<size; j++) {
            (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, row, j, (jobject)matrix[i][j]); // this line is 100% broken
        }

        if(tt==1) {
            tt=0;rows = (*env)->NewObjectArray(env, size, (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, row), 0);
        }

        (*env)->SetObjectArrayElement(env, rows, i, row);
    }

    return rows;
}
```

error i get:

```
Loaded generator.dll
counted total rects: 75
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x621e8551, pid=5336, tid=5704
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0-b75) (build 1.8.0-ea-b75)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.0-b17 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xc8551]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers
ions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\HnH\hs_err_pid5336.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

error log: http://wklej.to/1T2tW

i'd be glad for any clues what can be wrong in this as it's dark magic for me

Comment: Array(s) in Java are Objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the matrix is pSize * pSize, then you need new array of pSize firstly for returning, then new array and store in returnArray[i], and return the first array.

BTW, the code showing here is good candidate for a pure java implemetation. I guess the performance can be even better if it is called frequently.